# Overlapping titles in navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have ViewController with a button that animated pushes second viewController to navigation stack.

On that second controller I have a button with action that animated pop itself from navigation stack.

If i repeatedly and quickly press them one by one, titles in the navigation bar will overlap each other.

Here is a screenshot of overlapped titles:

[image]

How can I rid of this problem?

**Edit:**

I have same issue, it generates randomly.
I have `UIViewController` with `UITableView`, by tapping `UITableViewCell` it navigates to UITableViewController.

Sometimes `UITableViewController`'s title is overlapping with `UIViewController`'s title when I click on back button.

[image]

**NOTE:** There is no custom title or custom navigation items, all controls are default controls.

Navigation title was set using below code:

```
self.title = @"Mail (28)";
```

I'm using

> Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a)
>
> Simulator iPhone 7 - iOS10 (14A345)

Comment: Can you provide a picture of your problem ?

Comment: I have same issue, it generates randomly. I have `UIViewController` with tableView, by tapping tableViewCell it navigates to `UITableViewController`. Sometimes `UITableViewController`'s title is overlapping with `UIViewController`'s title when I click on back button.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your 1st `ViewController`, assign Blank String upon transition (line before you triggered the 2nd `ViewController`):

```
self.title = ""
```

And `onViewWillAppear()` of the 1st `ViewController`, reassign the

```
self.title = "previousvalue"
```